# Log offset, partition and topic from Kafka message

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I want to log or print offset, partition, and topic from Kafka's message.
I can print the message value but I want to see which offset and partition from Kafka using python so that I can debug my code

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',
                         group_id='my-group',
                         bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
for message in consumer:
    print(f"Message is {message.value()}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data should be available using dot notation

> The consumer iterator returns ConsumerRecords, which are simple namedtuples that expose basic message attributes: **topic, partition, offset**, key, and value:

https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python

Comment: I added an example code where I can print messages so can you help me with how to print offset, topic, and partition for the message, please.

Comment: I assume you have `print(msg.value)`? What issues are you having with `print(msg.topic, msg.partition, msg.offset)`?

Comment: When i print(msg.value) i get output as <built-in method topic of cimpl.Message object at 0x000001FCC73B4E48>

Comment: Well, [documentation shows `msg.value` is a dict when deserializing](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python#kafkaconsumer), not a function... If it is a function, then use `msg.value()` like you've shown in your question. You need to call the function... You could also `print(dir(msg))` to see all available attributes of the object

Comment: for msg.value() is working fine but I want to print offset, partition and for print(dir(msg)) I get output as ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', 
'__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'error', 'headers', 'key', 'latency', 'offset', 'partition', 'set_headers', 'set_key', 'set_value', 'timestamp', 'topic', 'value']

Comment: When i print(msg.offset) or print(msg.partition) i get output as <built-in method topic of cimpl.Message object at 0x000001FCC73B4E48>

Comment: That output is for `.topic`, not offset or partition... Again, as the output shows, those are methods that you need to call

Comment: logger.debug(f"Consumer data: offset-{message.offset()} partition-{message.partition()} topic-{message.topic()}") This worked for me thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('my-topic',
                         group_id='my-group',
                         bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
for message in consumer:
    logger.debug(f"Consumer data: offset-{message.offset()} partition-{message.partition()} topic-{message.topic()}")
    print(f"Message is {message.value()}")
```